# Compare two columns in csv files

Tags: python, python-3.x

There are `two csv files`, in the `first` file the `third column` has a certain number of rows with `data`, and in the `second file` the `first column` has similar data, also in some indefinite amount,
these are presented in the form of `md5`, for example:

file_1

| column_1 | column_2 | column_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| *blah blah blah* | *blah blah blah* | aa7744226c695c0b2e440419848cf700 |
| *blah blah blah* | *blah blah blah* | 9b34939b137e24f8c6603a54b2305f07 |
| *blah blah blah* | *blah blah blah* | ad1172b28f277eab7ca91f96f13a242b |
| `etc` |  |  |

file_2

| column_1 | column_2 | column_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 49269f413284abfa58f41687b6f631e0 | *blah blah blah* | *blah blah blah* |
| a0879ff97178e03eb18470277fbc7056 | *blah blah blah* | *blah blah blah* |
| 9e5b91c360d6be29d556db7e1241ce82 | *blah blah blah* | *blah blah blah* |
| `etc` |  |  |

Could you tell me please, how can i compare these two columns from two files, i.e. find `duplicate` values, and if the values are repeated, then display what value is in the first and second `csv file`.

I tried to take something from this example:

```
import csv    
interesting_cols = [0, 2, 3, 4, 5]    
with open("/root/file1.csv", 'r') as file1,\
     open("/root/file2.csv", 'r') as file2:    
    reader1, reader2 = csv.reader(file1), csv.reader(file2)    
    for line1, line2 in zip(reader1, reader2):
        equal = all(x == y for n, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(line1, line2)) if n in interesting_cols)
        print(equal)
```

this example would work well if two files would have only one column each. According to my requirements, I could not implement it in any way, I am very weak in Python.
Thank you very much!

Comment: Is [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/intro_tutorials/01_table_oriented.html) an option for reading/manipulating the data? It may be overkill for your needs, but it's a super-useful tabular-data-oriented library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer will work with **all records in files**. It will find match in all records in file1 and file2.

1. Reverse list `reader1 = [i[::-1] for i in reader1]` for ordering it.
2. Making a list of theese two `reader = reader1 + reader2`
3. Making a dictionary, which will find all matches by number.
4. Just printing result of our searching

```
import csv

interesting_cols = [0, 2, 3, 4, 5]
with open("file1.csv", 'r') as file1,\
     open("file2.csv", 'r') as file2:
    reader1, reader2 = csv.reader(file1), csv.reader(file2)

    reader1 = [i[::-1] for i in reader1]
    reader2 = [i for i in reader2]

    dictionary_of_records = {item[0]: [] for item in reader1}

    for i, item in enumerate(reader2):
        key = item[0]
        if key in dictionary_of_records:
            dictionary_of_records[key].append(i)

    for key, value in dictionary_of_records.items():
        if len(value) >= 1:
            print(f"Match for {key}")
            for index in value:
                print(' '.join(reader2[index]))
        else:
            print(f"No match for {key}")
        print("-----------------------------")
```

*P.S. It's quite hardcode, I think. You can also watch pandas library or itertools to find more beatiful way to do it.*

Comment: a good example, but it doesn't quite fit my needs, since there are duplicates in this or that file not only for md5 but also for other columns. I would like to find duplicates only in certain columns

Comment: @AlexRebell will the columns always be in the same order as shown in the example? or will it change from situation to situation? just now this solution is looking for a match among the entries of 3d columns in the first file and 1st column in the second

Comment: Sorry for replying so late. I'm sorry, I made a mistake in the question. I need to check for duplicates between the 4th column of the 1st file and the 1st column of the 2nd file. The 4th column in the 1st file is the last one. In the second file, in addition to the first column, there are two more, i.e. only 3, but the last two have no meaning. This arrangement of columns will always be static\unchanged.

Comment: I completely forgot to say that in the first file, the fourth column has duplicate data, there are a lot of them. Therefore, now when I use your code, I just get a search for duplicates from the first file and from the second file, and only in these columns, but not between them. In general, I need to search for all the values from the first file of the fourth column in the second file of the first column.

Comment: @AlexRebell Okay. I rewrited some code, please, check this one. In output you will see matches between 4th col on 1st file and 1st col in 2nd file

Comment: I started checking the operation of this code, and found that there is a small problem, if there are duplicates in the first file in the fourth column, then the search will still output as if there is one entry.

Comment: @AlexRebell Its quite hard to write an algorithm that will cover all the tests in a pure programming language. Either you have to dig deep into the mechanisms, or not very good code. It would be much easier if you read about Pandas library and what miracles it does) Based on your current task in your post, you will definitely have to write a lot of similar algorithms on your topic, and Pandas will be able to do it for you many times more efficiently

Answer (score 1):

If you are allowed, you can use Pandas to do that. Firstly install the package using pip:
`python -m pip install pandas`

or conda:
`conda install pandas`

And then read and compare with pandas:

**NOTE**: This only works in the case that both dataframes have the same structure like the same columns. If your dataframes are different and you are only interested on compare one or some columns between them, see bellow.

```py
import pandas as pd
interesting_cols = [0, 2, 3, 4, 5]    
file1 = pd.read_csv("/root/file1.csv")
file2 = pd.read_csv("/root/file2.csv")
comp = file1.compare(file2)
print(comp.to_markdown())
```

**OR**, if you prefer to keep the 'with' statement, you should create a class and define the `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods:

```py
import pandas as pd
interesting_cols = [0, 2, 3, 4, 5]    
class DataCSV:
    def __init__(self, file) -> None:
        self.filename = file
    def __enter__(self):
        self.file = pd.read_csv(self.filename)
        return self.file
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        pass
with DataCSV("/root/file1.csv") as file1, DataCSV("/root/file2.csv") as file2:
    comp = file1.compare(file2)
    print(comp.to_markdown())
```

The output should be something like:

|  | ('column_1', 'self') | ('column_1', 'other') | ('column_3', 'self') | ('column_3', 'other') |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | blah blah blah | 49269f413284abfa58f41687b6f631e0 | aa7744226c695c0b2e440419848cf700 | blah blah blah |
| 1 | blah blah blah | a0879ff97178e03eb18470277fbc7056 | 9b34939b137e24f8c6603a54b2305f07 | blah blah blah |
| 2 | blah blah blah | 9e5b91c360d6be29d556db7e1241ce82 | ad1172b28f277eab7ca91f96f13a242b | blah blah blah |

**EDIT 10/11/2021**
If you have two different CSV with different columns name/types and you are only interested on comparing one or some columns (like MD5 column), you can do using pandas too, but with the [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) method instead `compare`

```python
import pandas as pd
file1, file2 = pd.read_csv("file1.csv"), pd.read_csv("file2.csv")

mergedStuff = pd.merge(file1, file2, on=['MD5'], how='inner')
mergedStuff.head()
print(mergedStuff.to_markdown())
```

And this will print an inner from the columns where MD5 value matches:

|  | MD5 | Firstseen | Lastseen | Port |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a0879ff97178e03eb18470277fbc7056 | blah blah blah | blah blah blah | blah blah blah |

Comment: I couldn't check your example, there were a lot of errors :(

Comment: Humm, could you be more specific with the error? I tried before post and It worked for me

Comment: Your CSV files have header with column names? I'm assuming that, if not you should specify that your data does not have header.

Comment: In my CVS files, the first line is always the name. `MD5,Firstseen,Lastseen` and `Port,MD5`

Comment: ValueError: `Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects`

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
`comp = file1.compare(file2)`
`mask = ~((self == other) | (self.isna() & other.isna()))`
`self, other = ops.align_method_FRAME(self, other, axis, flex=False, level=None)`
`return method(self, other)`

Comment: Oh, I see. The `compare` method can only be used to compare two dataframes (like two csv) that have the same structure, like the same columns names. Otherwise, there are other ways to do it, but not with `compare` directly. Then I suppose that I misunderstood your question: do you want to compare then the MD5 column from the first CSV with the MD5 from the second one? Or how? Could you provide a simple expected input and output? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for replying so late. That's right, I want to compare hashes from two csv files and find matches. In the first csv file, the fourth column (by index) contains an md5 hash of 32 characters in each cell, there may be a different number of such rows. In the second file, the first column also has an md5 hash of 32 characters. And I just need to find matches between them, i.e. find matches. Thanks!

Comment: I edited my answer. May you want to check it and try if it works for your case.

Answer (score 0):

You can reorder a list and check it quickly using a generator.

```
import csv

def parse_csv(filename, header=False, delim=',', quotechar='"'):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        csvfile = csv.reader(f, delimiter=delim, quotechar=quotechar)
        if header:
            csvfile.__next__()
        for row in csvfile:
            yield row

def diff(l1, l2, reorder=None):
    if reorder:
        for i,line in enumerate(l2):
            l2[i] = [line[x] for x in reorder]
    for i, line in enumerate(l1):
        if line not in l2:
            yield i,  line

filename1 = ''
filename2 = ''
reorder = [2,1,0]

missing = [(i, line) for i,line in diff(parse_csv(filename1, header=False), list(parse_csv(filename2, header=False)), reorder=reorder) or (None, None)]
print(missing)
```

Comment: I couldn't check your example, there were a lot of errors:(for example: `missing = [(i, line) for i,line in diff(parse_csv(filename1, header=False), list(parse_csv(filename2, header=False)), reorder=reorder) or (None, None)]`

Comment: My code works perfectly fine if you feed it two files.  I tested this already with csv files.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader), it says *Each row read from the csv file is returned as a list of strings.* You can read individual columns from those lines.

For example:

Using two simple csv files
addresses.csv

```
Doe,John,120 jefferson st.,Riverside, NJ, 08075
McGinnis,Jack,220 hobo Av.,Phila, PA,09119
Repici,"John ""Da Man""",120 Jefferson St.,Riverside, NJ,08075
Tyler,Stephen,"7452 Terrace ""At the Plaza"" road",SomeTown,SD, 91234
```

and

phones.csv

```
John,Doe,19122
Jack,McGinnis,20220
"John ""Da Man""",Repici,1202134
Stephen,Tyler,72384


>>> with open('addresses.csv') as file1, open('phones.csv') as file2:
...     r1, r2 = csv.reader(file1), csv.reader(file2)
...     for line1, line2 in zip(r1, r2):
...             if line1[1] == line2[0]:
...                     print('found a duplicate', line1[1])
...
found a duplicate John
found a duplicate Jack
found a duplicate John "Da Man"
found a duplicate Stephen
```

we get the rows which have same values in specified columns. In our case, these are second column of first csv file and first column of second csv file. In order to get row numbers, you can use `enumerate(zip())` just like the example code you provided.

You can check [Python list comprehensions](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp) for the syntax used in your example.

Comment: this example is suitable only if the range of the cell being checked coincides with the range of the checking cell. i.e., when the first line in the first file coincides with the first line of the second file, and so on, and I would like that each was checked with each and output a duplicate, regardless of where and how the cells are located.